# How to determine the eigenvectors for this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have the matrix $$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-\alpha & \beta \\
\beta/K &  -\alpha/K
\end{array} \right)$$ for which the eigenvalues are $$\lambda_{1,2}=-\dfrac{\alpha}{2}-\dfrac{\beta}{2K}\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{(K\alpha-\beta)^2+4K\alpha\beta }}{2K}$$ I have a problem with finding the eigenvectors. It seems that the eigenvectors are zero vectors but then eigenvectors cannot be zero. What am I missing?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then $A-\lambda I$ is a singular matrix, and the corresponding eigenvector is a non-zero vector in its nullspace. How are you calculating eigenvectors?

Comment: I believe you said eigenvectors when you meant so say eigenvalues so I have changed it for you.

Comment: I would say that after adjustment be: $\lambda_1=0,\,\,\lambda_2=-\frac{K\alpha+\beta}{K}$

Comment: When I calculate these eigenvalues, I get $\lambda_{1,2}=-\frac{(K+1)\alpha}{2K} \pm \frac{\sqrt{(K-1)^2\alpha^2 + 4K\beta^2}}{2K}$. Are you sure of your eigenvalues?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't exchange $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the second row?

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is of the form $$M=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b/k & a/k \end{pmatrix},$$
now let $x=(x_1,x_2) \neq (0,0)$ be such that $Mx = \lambda x$, then 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} =Mx-\lambda x  =\begin{pmatrix} (a-\lambda)x_1+bx_2 \\ \frac{1}{k}(bx_1 +(a-k\lambda)x_2) \end{pmatrix}, $$
This a two unknown linear system of two equations. Solving it shows directly that your eigenvectors must have the form 
$$\alpha\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ b/(\lambda-a)\end{pmatrix}, \quad  \alpha \in \mathbb{R}.$$
if $\lambda \neq a$ (use the first equation) and 
$$\alpha\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \quad  \alpha \in \mathbb{R}.$$
if $\lambda  = a$ (from the first equation you get $x_2=0$). Since you aleready computed the eigenvalues, it shouldn't be hard to recover the eigenvectors for your special case.

Comment: Your matrix is not quite the same as posters, regards the positions of $a$ and $b$. But I think the original question should be checked for mistakes, I am not confident in the calculation of the eigenvalues given.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus It has been edited (thanks I mixed the components). Seems that georg checked the eigenvalues (see comments of the OP).

Comment: Yeah I thought something was off, I am deleting my answer which was based on the false computation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To find the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$, we solve $\mathrm{det}(A-\lambda I)=0$ for $\lambda$. In this case:

$\begin{align}
\left|\begin{array}{cc} -\alpha-\lambda & \beta \\ \frac{\beta}{K} &  \frac{-\alpha}{K}-\lambda \end{array}\right| &= (-\alpha-\lambda)\left(\frac{-\alpha}{K}-\lambda\right)-\frac{\beta^2}{K} \\
&=\frac{\alpha^2}{K}+\left(\alpha+\frac{\alpha}{K}\right)\lambda + \lambda^2 - \frac{\beta^2}{K} \\
&=\lambda^2 + \left(\alpha+\frac{\alpha}{K}\right)\lambda + \frac{\alpha^2-\beta^2}{K} = 0,
\end{align}$

implies that our eigenvalues are:

$\begin{align}
\lambda_{1,2} &= -\frac{\alpha+\frac{\alpha}{K}}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{\left(\alpha+\frac{\alpha}{K}\right)^2 - 4\frac{\alpha^2-\beta^2}{K}}}{2} \\
&=-\frac{K\alpha+\alpha}{2K} \pm \frac{\sqrt{(K\alpha+\alpha)^2 - 4K(\alpha^2-\beta^2)}}{2K} \\
&=-\frac{(K+1)\alpha}{2K} \pm \frac{\sqrt{\left((K+1)^2-4K\right)\alpha^2 + 4K\beta^2}}{2K} \\
&=-\frac{(K+1)\alpha}{2K} \pm \frac{\sqrt{(K-1)^2\alpha^2 + 4K\beta^2}}{2K}.
\end{align}$

Now, an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ is in the nullspace of $\left(\begin{array}{cc} -\alpha-\lambda_i & \beta \\ \frac{\beta}{K} &  \frac{-\alpha}{K}-\lambda_i \end{array}\right).$

It appears that the vector $\bf{v}_i=\left(\begin{array}{c} \beta \\ \alpha + \lambda_i \end{array}\right)$ would work.

Comment: How are you getting v? Row operations give $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\lambda_i}\\
0 & \frac{\alpha-K\lambda_i}{\beta}
\end{array} \right)$ from which $v_2$ is zero

Comment: Since $A-\lambda I$ is singular, I'm not bothering with row operations, and just writing down a vector that kills row 1. If you multiply my $v_i$ by my matrix $A-\lambda I$, you get a $0$ on top.